# How to trigger an action based on the user's view on the page in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to have a single page in Angular with multiple subsections which can be either reached by seemless scrolling down or by clicking on the list of sections.
If the user clicks on the section, an action to scroll into the section is triggered and the particular section is highlighted in which the user is currently located in the page.

How is it possible to track when the user reaches a specific section by scrolling to trigger the colour highlighting correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You can get your sections via @ViewChild or @ViewChildren.

mark them inside html with `<div #section>...`

inside ts:

```js
...
@ViewChildren('section') sections: QueryList<ElementRef>; // getting your sections here

@HostListener('scroll') scrolling() {
  this.checkScrollPosition();
}

@HostListener('resize') scrolling() {
  this.checkScrollPosition();
}

currentSectionId: number;

constructor(private readonly renderer: Renderer2) {}

checkScrollPosition(): void {
  // check if your inside your section here by using window.scrollTop and sections[anyIndex].nativeElement.scrollTop

  // if your using angular universal you can use Angulars ViewportScroller


  renderer.removeClass(sections[this.currentSectionId].nativeElement, 'class-with-color');

  this.currentSectionId = anyIndex // the index you got by searching for the current section

  renderer.addClass(sections[this.currentSectionId].nativeElement, 'class-with-color');
}
```

The HostListeners Observes resize and scrolling events to check if your inside the current section.

I was to lazy to write how to find the current sections, I hope this answers your question anyway :D

ps. I haven't tested the code, but it should similar like that

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't aware of HostListener, with that it will be possible to implement the idea.